# If name from one sheet is found on another mark checkbox on 1st sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for help with a script to where if the name in column E of the first sheet "July Log" is in Column C of second sheet "DT NEW" where column F has either "Booked or Funded" it will go back to the "July Log" and check the box in column D. Else do nothing.

I'm not a coder or scripter just trying to teach myself. I've done a lot just from searching but I've tried a few different routes on this one and no luck. 
Thanks for any help. Preferable broken down on an elementary level lol

[July Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnKnd.png)

[DTNEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2e52.png)

Comment: Include the code you've tried to use to achieve this in your question.

Comment: Find more information about writing Apps Script code here: developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and here:developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("July Log");
var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("DT NEW");
var i=0;
var j=0;
for(i=1;i<=sheet1.getLastRow();i++)
{
  for(j=1;j<=sheet2.getLastRow();j++)
  {
    if(sheet2.getRange(i, 3).getValue() == sheet1.getRange(j, 5).getValue())
    {
      if(sheet2.getRange(i, 6).getValue() == "Funded" || sheet2.getRange(i, 6).getValue() == "Booked")
    {
      sheet1.getRange(i,4).activate();
      sheet1.getCurrentCell().setValue('TRUE');
    }
  }      
}}
```

Edit as you wish.

try the new code .. i have used getValues() instead of getValue().

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("July Log");
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("DT NEW");
  var i=0;
  var j=0;
  var namedata1 = sheet1.getRange("E1:E3").getValues();
  var namedata2 = sheet2.getRange("C:C").getValues();
  var status = sheet2.getRange("F:F").getValues();
  for(i=0;i<sheet1.getLastRow();i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<sheet2.getLastRow();j++)
    {
      if(namedata2[i][0] == namedata1[j][0])
      {
        if(status[i][0] == "Funded" || status[i][0] == "Booked")
        {
          sheet1.getRange(i+1,4).activate();
          sheet1.getCurrentCell().setValue('TRUE');
        }
      }      
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Void! It's still not working though. It was running for a couple of mins then gave a message:                                                                                                Method Range.getValue is heavily used by the script.
File: Code Line: 30
The script uses a method which is considered expensive. Each invocation generates a time-consuming call to a remote server. That may have a critical impact on the execution time of the script, especially on large data. If performance is an issue for the script, you should consider using another method, e.g. Range.getValues().

Comment: Hi @DwayneLivingston ..try the new code ...i just used getValues(). Let me know if this works for you.